# Saving most viewed pages, likes etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this project where I load data from an `XML-file` with `Javascript`. The first page is filled with pictures and their title. Everything works fine, but I want to know what has been viewed (clicked) the most. If you click on the picture, it will give you more info.

So, how can I do that? I want to keep it even if you refresh the page. I'm sure you'll have a solution in your head atm but I don't work with `MySql` nor do I work with `php`. Is there an alternative? I was think about editing the XML-file but I'm not sure if that's possible with `jQuery/Javascript`

Thanks in advance